# End date must be equal and greater than start selected date in boostrap

Tags: datepicker

**Requirements** - End date must be equal and greater then start selected start date in boostrap datepicker and before selected start date disable.

**Problem** - its possible in jquery date but I want to know how to make in boostrap date.

my boostrap code is

```
 $('#start_date').datepicker({autoclose: true,startDate: new Date()});
 $('#end_date').datepicker({autoclose: true,startDate: new Date()});
```

for reference check jquery code 
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wakeel/3Ljr3yc4/)

**Note** - I want exact implemention of this picker in bootstrap
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please check out [this JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0fpug46n/). I have placed the code below that uses bootstrap datepicker.

```
$(".from_date").datepicker({
  format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
  autoclose: true,
}).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
    var startDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
    $('.to_date').datepicker('setStartDate', startDate);
}).on('clearDate', function (selected) {
    $('.to_date').datepicker('setStartDate', null);
});

$(".to_date").datepicker({
   format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
   autoclose: true,
}).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
   var endDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
   $('.from_date').datepicker('setEndDate', endDate);
}).on('clearDate', function (selected) {
   $('.from_date').datepicker('setEndDate', null);
});
```